# Facebook site url different from canvas url

Tags: facebook, node.js, facebook-graph-api, heroku, facebook-apps

I have a running facebook application (canvas app) on one hosting account.
I tried to create an external website with facebook login using Heroku Node.js, and use this new hosting (the original app created has a different secret and app_id.

If I change the environment variables (secret and app_id) to use my existing (old) app, when I try to run FB calls, I get 'Unsupported get request, error code 100', and the app will not allow any calls.

If I get back to the original app_id and secret given by heroku default - it works well.

Any idea what is the problem? must site url be the same as the canvas url?